# How to change state outside of a view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, menubarextra

I have a menubar-only (Mac) SwiftUI app. The core of it is this:

```swift
// MyMainApp.swift
var body: some Scene {
    MenuBarExtra("My App", image: "LoggedOutIcon") {
        MenuBarView()
    }
}
```

I'd like to dynamically update the image to "LoggedInIcon" whenever the user is logged in, and "LoggedOutIcon" whenever the user is logged out. That functionality is set in a (non-view) controller.

I figured the way to do this was to pass in my main controller to my app like this:

```swift
// MyMainApp.swift
@StateObject var myMainController = MyMainController()
```

Within that, set a published variable like this:

```swift
// MyMainController.swift
@Published var loggedIn: Bool = false
```

And then update the MenuBarExtra call to

```swift
// MyMainApp.swift
MenuBarExtra("My App", image: myMainController.loggedIn ? "LoggedInIcon" : "LoggedOutIcon")
```

The good news is: it works. The bad news is, that `@StateObject var myMainController` line raises the following purple notification of doom:

> Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This
> will create a new instance each time.

...That seems like something I should avoid.

In short: what is the best practice for updating a `MenuBarExtra` icon in a SwiftUI app outside the scope of a view?

Comment: Don't use `@StateObject`. You can simply create an object and pass it as a parameter to the view or put it in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `loggedIn` property is toggled by a view further down in your hierarchy-- e.g. in `MenuBarView`:

```swift
struct MenuBarView: View {
    @Binding var loggedIn: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { loggedIn.toggle() }) {
            Text(loggedIn ? "Log Out" : "Log In")
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `@AppStorage` property wrapper and in `MyMainApp.Swift`:

```swift
@AppStorage("loggedIn") private var loggedIn = false
var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("My App", image: loggedIn ? "LoggedInIcon" : "LoggedOutIcon") {
            MenuBarView(loggedIn: $loggedIn)
        }
    }
```

If you want it to be toggled in the `MyMainController`, you'd still use `@AppStorage` but instead of having a `@Binding` to it in a View, you'd do:

```swift
// MyMainController.swift
var loggedIn: Bool {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(loggedIn, forKey: "loggedIn")
        }
    }
```

[If you're interested in *why* swift is showing you this error, there is a good discussion about it here](https://forums.swift.org/t/explanation-behind-the-error-accessing-stateobjects-object-without-being-installed-on-a-view-this-will-create-a-new-instance-each-time/40111)